# Custom Legend with ChartJS v2.0

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to create a custom legend template in ChartJS v2.0.  In v1* of ChartJS I simply added a property to the new Chart constructor such as...

```
legendTemplate : '<ul>'
+'<% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++) { %>'
+'<li>'
+'<span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].lineColor%>\"></span>'
+'<% if (datasets[i].label) { %><%= datasets[i].label %><% } %>'
+'</li>'
+'<% } %>'
+'</ul>'
```

I can't seem to find any documentation in v2.0 for this option.  Is it even available anymore?  Can anyone show an example of how to accomplish this?

Thank you!

**Update - Working code below**

```
legendCallback: function(chart) {
                console.log(chart.data);
                var text = [];
                text.push('<ul>');
                for (var i=0; i<chart.data.datasets[0].data.length; i++) {
                    text.push('<li>');
                    text.push('<span style="background-color:' + chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[i] + '">' + chart.data.datasets[0].data[i] + '</span>');
                    if (chart.data.labels[i]) {
                        text.push(chart.data.labels[i]);
                    }
                    text.push('</li>');
                }
                text.push('</ul>');
                return text.join("");
            }
```

Comment: Is it possible if you could post a snippet of the whole chart options?

Comment: [4 charts | Chart JS | with a single custom legend](https://codepen.io/shivabhusal/pen/zdpOgy)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is a `legendCallback` function:

> **legendCallback**    *Function*  `function (chart) { }`
>   Function to generate a legend. Receives the chart object to generate a legend from. Default
>   implementation returns an HTML string.

[Details can be found here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#html-legends)

[see this issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5070) for the default legend callback:

```
legendCallback: function(chart) { 
    var text = []; 
    text.push('<ul class="' + chart.id + '-legend">'); 
    for (var i = 0; i < chart.data.datasets.length; i++) { 
        text.push('<li><span style="background-color:' + 
                   chart.data.datasets[i].backgroundColor + 
                   '"></span>'); 
        if (chart.data.datasets[i].label) { 
            text.push(chart.data.datasets[i].label); 
        } 
        text.push('</li>'); 
    } 
    text.push('</ul>'); 
    return text.join(''); 
}
```

Comment: Possible to show example of how this is to be used to generate custom legend?

Comment: also how do you HIDE the default legend that is generated?    Any ideas?

Comment: This method generates the legend so I would imagine that if you added your own implementation it would automatically overide the default

Comment: it does not appear to do so.  I have implemented a custom legend using the legendCallback (updated my post above too to show my function) and it does generate my legend properly, however the default legend above the chart is still present.

Comment: figured it out... I had to add legend: { display: false } to the options

Comment: Hey, I havent used chart.js so was having a look for some examples, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 33):

If you guys run through this post and tried the posted answer and didn't work,
try this one:

```
  legendCallback: function(chart) {
    var text = [];
    text.push('<ul>');
    for (var i=0; i<chart.data.datasets.length; i++) {
      console.log(chart.data.datasets[i]); // see what's inside the obj.
      text.push('<li>');
      text.push('<span style="background-color:' + chart.data.datasets[i].borderColor + '">' + chart.data.datasets[i].label + '</span>');
      text.push('</li>');
    }
    text.push('</ul>');
    return text.join("");
  },
```

Then add this below:

```
document.getElementById('chart-legends').innerHTML = myChart.generateLegend();
```

To create the legends. Make sure you have an element `<div id="chart-legends"></div>`

Comment: To get this to work in React I had to dangerouslySetInnerHtml on a JSX component: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: Thanks! Why array but not string?

Comment: @Antfish can you please show me how did you use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?

Comment: Does this work for ChartJS `3.1`?

Answer (score 17):

I hope this will helpful you

```js
var configd = {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: [
                50,
                60,
                20
            ],           
            backgroundColor: [
                '#33b35a',
                "#ffce56",
                "#4bc0c0",
                "#CDDC39",
                "#9C27B0",
                "#fb7145",
                "#5971f9"
            ],
            label: 'Energy usage'
        }],
        labels: [
            'E1',
            'E2',
            'E3'
        ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        legendCallback: function (chart) {             
            // Return the HTML string here.
            console.log(chart.data.datasets);
            var text = [];
            text.push('<ul class="' + chart.id + '-legend">');
            for (var i = 0; i < chart.data.datasets[0].data.length; i++) {
                text.push('<li><span id="legend-' + i + '-item" style="background-color:' + chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[i] + '"   onclick="updateDataset(event, ' + '\'' + i + '\'' + ')">');
                if (chart.data.labels[i]) {
                    text.push(chart.data.labels[i]);
                }
                text.push('</span></li>');
            }
            text.push('</ul>');
            return text.join("");
        },
        title: {
            display: false,
            text: 'Chart.js Doughnut Chart'
        },
        animation: {
            animateScale: true,
            animateRotate: true
        },
        tooltips: {
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: false,
            callbacks: {
                label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                    let label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ' - ' + data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
                    let datasetLabel = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                    return label + ': ' + datasetLabel.toLocaleString();
                }
            }
        },
    }
};

 var ctxd = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    
    window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctxd, configd);
    $("#do_legend").html(window.myDoughnut.generateLegend());

// Show/hide chart by click legend
updateDataset = function (e, datasetIndex) {    
    var index = datasetIndex;
    var ci = e.view.myDoughnut;
    var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(0);    
    var result= (meta.data[datasetIndex].hidden == true) ? false : true;
    if(result==true)
    {
        meta.data[datasetIndex].hidden = true;
        $('#' + e.path[0].id).css("text-decoration", "line-through");
    }else{
        $('#' + e.path[0].id).css("text-decoration","");
        meta.data[datasetIndex].hidden = false;
    }
     
    ci.update();   
};
```

```css
#do_legend{
   height:62px;
}

#do_legend{
    width:100%;     
}

#do_legend> ul{
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
 

#do_legend {   
  width:100%;
  bottom:10%;
}
#do_legend li {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 4px 3px;
    display: inline-table;
}
#do_legend li span {
    position: relative;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    color: white;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 11px;
}

#do_legend{
    height: 62px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.donut-area{
    height:calc(100% - 62px)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>


<div style="width:40%">
   <div id="do_legend"></div>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/udarakasun/pen/QYLgeM)

Answer (score 2):

If people come here looking for a solution for this in **ChartJS 3.6.0**. (Maybe other versions too)

They offer an HTML legend where you can specify the exact HTML you want using the plugins option.
Here is an example of the configuration along with the link to the documentation below.

```
  const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    plugins: {
      htmlLegend: {
        // ID of the container to put the legend in
        containerID: 'legend-container',
      },
      legend: {
        display: false,
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [htmlLegendPlugin],
};
```

[ChartJS HTML Legend](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/docs/samples/legend/html.md)

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me

```
updateDataset = function(target, chart, label, color, data) {
    var store = chart.data.datasets[0].label;
    var bgcolor = chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor;
    var dataSets = chart.data.datasets[0].data;
    var exists = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < chart.data.datasets[0].label.length; i++) {
        if (chart.data.datasets[0].label[i] === label) {
            chart.data.datasets[0].label
            exists = true;
            chart.data.datasets[0].label.push(store.splice(i, 1)[0][1]);
            chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor.push(bgcolor.splice(i, 1)[0][1]);
            chart.data.datasets[0].data.push(dataSets.splice(i, 1)[0][1]);      
        }
    }
    if (!exists) {
        chart.data.datasets[0].label.push(label);
        chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor.push(color);
        chart.data.datasets[0].data.push(data);
        exists = false;
    }
    chart.update();  
};
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

**ChartJS 3.0+**

I know this question is specifically asking about chartJS 2.0, but this is one of the biggest threads I've found addressing custom legends in chartJS, so I wanted to share my finding for adding a custom legend in chartJS 3.0+ which deprecated the use of the `generateLegend()` function.

Adding a legend in chartJS 3.0+ requires the use of [plugins](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html).

Basically you can create a custom plugin when you instantiate the chart. For example:

```
const context = document.querySelector("#chart-id");
const chart = new Chart(context, {
  type: "doughnut",
  data,
  options,
  plugins: [{
    beforeInit: function(chart, args, options) {
      // Make sure we're applying the legend to the right chart
      if (chart.canvas.id === "chart-id") {
        const ul = document.createElement('ul');
        chart.data.labels.forEach((label, i) => {
          ul.innerHTML += `
            <li>
              <span style="background-color: ${ chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[i] }">
                ${ chart.data.datasets[0].data[i] }
              </span>
              ${ label }
            </li>
          `;
        });

        return document.getElementById("js-legend").appendChild(ul);
      }

      return;
    }
  }]  
});
```

Here's a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kingliam/8vephjfu/43/) illustrating this method of adding a custom legend.