# generateLegend() Chart.JS V2

Tags: dom, chart.js, legend-properties

I´m trying to customize my legend

I´m using the .generateLegend() to get the legend in a html way

this is what the function gave me

```
console.log(myBarChart.generateLegend());

<ul class="1-legend"><li><span style="background-color:#006666"></span>SECRETARIA MUNICIPAL DE DESENVOLVIMENTO URBANO </li>
    <li><span style="background-color:#339966"></span>SECRETARIA MUNICIPAL DE SAUDE</li>
    <li><span style="background-color:#3366ff"></span>SETOR DE RH</li>
    <li><span style="background-color:#66ccff"></span>SECRETARIA MUNICIPAL DE CULTURA, TURISMO, ESPORTE E LAZER </li>
    <li><span style="background-color:#ffcc66"></span>SETOR DE CADASTRO DE IMOVEIS</li>
    <li><span style="background-color:#ff6666"></span>SECRETARIA MUNICIPAL DE DESENVOLVIMENTO ECONÔMICO, TRABALHO E MEIO AMBIENTE</li>
<li><span style="background-color:#994d00"></span>SETOR AGILIZA</li></ul>
```

Even the span style has the background color it shows this way in page:

SECRETARIA MUNICIPAL DE DESENVOLVIMENTO URBANO

SECRETARIA MUNICIPAL DE SAUDE

SETOR DE RH

SECRETARIA MUNICIPAL DE CULTURA, TURISMO, ESPORTE E LAZER

SETOR DE CADASTRO DE IMOVEIS

SECRETARIA MUNICIPAL DE DESENVOLVIMENTO ECONÔMICO, TRABALHO E MEIO AMBIENTE

SETOR AGILIZA

How can i show the color passed in the span style tag in the HTML?

I tried to make this way too but i can´t understand how to get it work ([Custom Legend with ChartJS v2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37005297/custom-legend-with-chartjs-v2-0)

Thx for your time!

**UPDATE 1**

As @Quince pointed i need to change the '1-legend' that the function gave to me

To remove the 1-legend of class name i used

```
var s = myBarChart.generateLegend().replace(/\"1-legend"/g, 'legend');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved through some css. First thing though you css class `1-legend` is not valid, css class names can not start with a number ([good explanation on what is allowed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/449000/2737978))

But once that is fixed you can just style the spans how you want to dispaly here is an example

```css
.legend {
  list-style: none;
}

.legend li span {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="legend">
  <li><span style="background-color:#006666"></span>SECRETARIA MUNICIPAL DE DESENVOLVIMENTO URBANO </li>
  <li><span style="background-color:#339966"></span>SECRETARIA MUNICIPAL DE SAUDE</li>
  <li><span style="background-color:#3366ff"></span>SETOR DE RH</li>
  <li><span style="background-color:#66ccff"></span>SECRETARIA MUNICIPAL DE CULTURA, TURISMO, ESPORTE E LAZER </li>
  <li><span style="background-color:#ffcc66"></span>SETOR DE CADASTRO DE IMOVEIS</li>
  <li><span style="background-color:#ff6666"></span>SECRETARIA MUNICIPAL DE DESENVOLVIMENTO ECONÔMICO, TRABALHO E MEIO AMBIENTE</li>
  <li><span style="background-color:#994d00"></span>SETOR AGILIZA</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The class name is given automatically by the function  .generateLegend()

But i use 
var s = myBarChart.generateLegend().replace(/\"1-legend"/g, 'Legend');
to change to a valid way.

thx a lot for your time

Answer (score 1):

```
.legend {
    margin-top: 30px;

    ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;

        li {
            padding-left: 28px;
            position: relative;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: 600;

            span {
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                position: absolute;
                left: 0px;
                top: 3px;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, you can paste ul into your own structure by:

```
document.getElementById('name-of-your-element').innerHTML = myBarChart.generateLegend();
```