# Add percentage to label badge - doughnut chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, chart.js

I wasn't able to figure out, how to enter percentage into labels badge like this image below.

I'm using this laravel wrapper : https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts
so was the reason I didn't want to confuse viewers.
I just want to know the name of the option.

My code is this:

```
$perTopicChart = (new AnsweredPerTopic);//->percentageInnerCutout(70);
    $perTopicChart->options([
        "events" => [],
        "legend" => [
            "labels" => [
                "defaultFontFamily" => "Tahoma",
                "fontSize" => 16,
            ],
            "position" => 'bottom'
        ],
        "cutoutPercentage" => 80,
        'tooltips' => [
            "show" => true
        ]
    ])->displayAxes(0);

    // put the labels (keys)
    $perTopicChart->labels($keys->map(function ($q) use ($perTopic) {
        $topic = Topic::find($q);
        $str = $topic->name;
        foreach ($perTopic as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == $q) {
                $str .= ' ' . round($value) . '%';
            }
        }
        return "topic name " . '-'. $topic->id;
         
    })->push('other'))
    ->options([]);
    // get random color 
    // $color = RandomColor::many(count($keys), array(
    //     'luminosity' => 'bright',
    //     'hue' => ['pink', 'green', 'orange'] // e.g. 'rgb(225,200,20)'
    //     ));
    $color = [
        "#38c172",
        "#9F9",
        "#Fa0",
        "pink",
        "red",
    ];
    
    $perTopicChart->dataset("Practice per Category", "doughnut", $values->map(function ($q) {
        return round($q);
    })->push($remainingPercenteg))
        ->backgroundColor($color)
        ->options([
            'borderWidth' => 2.5,
        ]);
```

The first image the current result and the second is what I wanted.

[image: the current result]
[image: what I want to achieve]

Comment: And your code is ? What have you tried? What are you getting in the output?

Comment: Thanks kenny for giving feedback, I updated the question, any help is appreciated.

Comment: even I researched a lot for this couldn't find anything, just thought of hack, something like, instead of letting chartjs to draw the legends, we should draw it on our side. Like get html of legends from chart js and draw it on our side. This is more of a hack. If you want the code of it, I can provide you an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I researched a lot, couldn't find anything for this kind of behavior in chartjs library, So come up with a hack.

Hack is something like, Do not let chart js to draw legends, Instead we just get the HTML of legends from chart js library, and put it in our container. By doing this we have full access of legends and we can do whatever we want.

https://jsfiddle.net/1kxenzpr/

```js
const data = [70, 30, 0];
debugger;
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ["Green", "Blue", "Gray", "Purple", "Yellow", "Red", "Black"],
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: [
        "#2ecc71",
        "#3498db",
        "#95a5a6",
        "#9b59b6",
        "#f1c40f",
        "#e74c3c",
        "#34495e"
      ],
      data: data
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
  }
});
var myLegendContainer = document.getElementById("legend");
myLegendContainer.innerHTML = chart.generateLegend();
var legendItems = myLegendContainer.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < legendItems.length; i++) {
  legendItems[i].querySelectorAll('span')[0].innerHTML = data[i] + '%'
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

[class$="-legend"] {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 0;
}

[class$="-legend"] li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

[class$="-legend"] li.hidden {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

[class$="-legend"] li span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    <div id="legend"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**No way** (By setting X or Y). You should use `legendCallback`:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#html-legends

Anyway, this is +- the idea (convert to % by basic JS). To take this step forward you should generate **full** generate HTML legend (To put a number inside a color div). Related: [Custom Legend with ChartJS v2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37005297/custom-legend-with-chartjs-v2-0/37005433)

```js
var myData = [4, 9, 5];

var data = {
  labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "Population (millions)",
    backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f"],
    data: myData
  }]
};

/* get total */
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
var total = myData.reduce(reducer);

var options = {
  responsive: true,
  title: {
    text: 'Show % calucate on fly',
    position: 'top',
    display: true
  },
  legend: {
    display: true,
    labels: {
      /* generateLabels */
      generateLabels(chart) {
        const data = chart.data;
        if (data.labels.length && data.datasets.length) {
          /* inner loop throw lables */
          return data.labels.map((label, i) => {
            var backgroundColor = data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[i];
            var current = data.datasets[0].data[i];
            var percentage =  ((current * 100) / total).toFixed(2) + '%'; 
            return {
              text: label + " | " + percentage,
              fillStyle: backgroundColor,
              // Extra data used for toggling the correct item
              index: i
            };
          });
        }
        return [];
      }

    },

  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      display: true
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      display: true
    }]
  }
};


new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: 'pie',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```html
<canvas id="chart" width="800" height="450"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
```